# MPMoviePlayerController and play audio from other apps, such as spotify, in background

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I use the MPMoviePlayerController and I would like the user to be able to watch a video that contains audio, and be able to continue listening to their Spotify or other music app already running in the background. How can I allow my app to play a movie and allow the user to continue listening to music?

```
        self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if var player = self.moviePlayer {
            // let the preview loop
            self.stopPreview = false
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden=true
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            player.controlStyle = .None
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)

            // custom UI preview controlls
            // Back button and send buttons
            self.view.addSubview(self.confirmationView)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.confirmationView)
        }
```

Comment: Hi, did you got any solution ?

Comment: Let me know if you find it. I moved on to another project, but this really interested me a few years ago.